# Enter feet and inches in 0-00 format

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to enter feet and inches in a 0-00 format with 1/4 increments.

Examples:
1'3" = 1-03
2'5 1/4" = 2-051
10'9 1/2" = 10-092
22'10 3/4" = 22-103

I have a user form setup that I would like the user to be able to enter dimension as above. However, all my formulas are setup for feet and inches in decimal. So after the user enters the data I would need it to be converted to decimal.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You need to post your code and what the problem is.

Comment: *All my formulas are setup for feet in decimal* - situation much improved since 1960; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the input as text...

1. First 2 digits after the "-" character get divided by 12
2. Last digit gets divided by 4 then by 12
3. Add everything together

So, for example, 2-051 =

```
2
+ 05/12 = 0.41666
+ (1/4)/12 = .020833
= 2.4375
```

In VBA, a function for this would look as follows:

```
Function ParseHeight(ht As String) As Double

Dim Feet As Integer
Dim Inches As Integer
Dim Quarters As Integer

Dim DashLocation As Integer

    DashLocation = InStr(1, ht, "-")

    Feet = Mid(ht, 1, DashLocation - 1)
    Inches = Mid(ht, DashLocation + 1, 2)
    If Len(ht) = DashLocation + 3 Then Quarters = Mid(ht, DashLocation + 3, 1)

    ParseHeight = Feet + (Inches / 12) + ((Quarters / 4) / 12)
End Function
```

---

Given that you want to do this via formulas in Excel:

(Assuming input in `E1`, try this formula in F1):

```
=LEFT(E1,FIND("-",E1)-1)+MID(E1,FIND("-",E1)+1,2)/12+IFERROR((MID(E1,FIND("-",E1)+3,1)/4)/12,0)
```

And, then, to convert a number from decimal back to your format, this would do it:

(Assuming decimal to be converted is in F1):

```
=INT(F1)&"-"&TEXT(INT(MOD(F1,1)*12),"00")&INT(MOD(MOD(F1,1)*12,1)*4)
```

Comment: Ok, I am close I think. I am so inexperienced at this and I appreciate you help.
Lets say E2 = 2-051
I have F2 as 
    =LEFT(E2,FIND("-",E2)-1)+((MID(E2,FIND("-",E2)+1,LEN(E2)-FIND("-",E2)-1))/12)
But it is only reading the 2-05 part. Also If I only put in 2-05 it doesn't work at all.
And then I also need to the opposite and take a decimal and change it to the 0-00 format. Example: Take 2.4375 and make it 2-051

Comment: I copied it over and gave it a go, but it didn't calculate right.
E1=2-051   F1=2.4167   G1=2-053
    Looks like the formula in F1 isn't working right.

Comment: @MarkSmith, I just copied mine across and got 2.4375 in F1.... I have **no clue** how you got your value in F1... I just copied and pasted

Comment: I copied and pasted the first time as well. But I just did it again and it works perfect. Thank you for all your help.